# Contar caracteres obtenidos de un campo de una tabla en MYSQL con PHP y obtener la cantidad independiente de ese campo en cada dato hallado

Tags: php

Estoy buscando mostrar la cantidad de caracteres del campo *likes* probé con *count()* pero solo me retorna un **1** en el div como resultado pero hay 19 carácteres en total en el primer dato de la tabla, además de esto me gustaría que el resultado de los carácteres fuera independiente por cada campo *like* de la lista, ya que si quito el *where* pues retorna toda la lista y con ello la cantidad de carácteres en el campo *likes* es el total de campos *likes* de la lista.

```js
<?php
include("question_database.php");

$result = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $t1 WHERE id = '458547854758'");

while ($post = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '
    
    <div>'.'¿'.$post['title'].'?'.'</div>
    
    <div>'.$post['description'].'</div>
    
    <div>'.count($post['likes']).'</div> 
    
    
    ';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion count en PHP es para obtener el total de elementos de un array o un objeto, si lo que quieres obtener la cantidad de caracteres de un campo del array que devuelve tu query usa la funcion strlen, solo asegurate de pasar un elemento de tipo string (texto) y no un array